# Fake Single Wordpress Post (Page) Loop

Tags: plugins, loop, pages, templates

In a plugin, I am building a custom page with

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){
    include(TEMPLATEPATH."/page.php");
    exit();
});
add_filter('the_title', function(){ return "Virtual Page Title"; });
add_filter('the_content', function(){ ?>
    <!-- HTML CONTENT -->
<?php }); ?>
```

But some templates wrap the `page.php` content calls in a `have_posts()` loop which I need to override for the virtual page. I have tried `query_posts('posts_per_page=1')` but that requires that there is at least one published post, which may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this instead:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){
    get_header();
    echo 'page stuff';
    get_footer();
    exit();
});
add_filter('the_title', function(){ return "Virtual Page Title"; });
```

What you are trying to do strikes me as very prone to error. Different themes can do all kinds of different things with `page.php`, not to mention that it may not be present at all.

What you are doing actually works when I test it on Twenty Thirteen. If you are have trouble with some theme or another, take that as evidence of the preceding point-- this strikes me as prone to error. A lot of things happen in themes that your plugin has no control over. If you are going to create a page you probably need to create the bulk of it yourself.